# how to simulate android emulator boot in AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi every one I'm currently working on a project which i need to monitor app behavior on emulator boot (i have a broadcast receiver which is being triggered with boot complete) the problem is the logcat shows process is terminated when you restart the emulator.

any idea how can simulate the boot and see logs in logcat???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your emulator, go to Settings -> System -> Developer Options. Under 'Debugging' go to "Select debug app" and find your app, then underneath that option enable "Wait for debugger". Now when you reboot the emulator, the dialog to attach the debugger will show asking you to manually attach your debugger. Once you do that, your app will start and the receiver will get triggered.

Android studio emulators restart by long-pressing the power button and choosing "Restart". If you want to simulate the request instead you can use the following command:

```
adb shell su root am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Comment: I get this error when sunning the abd shell command: /system/bin/sh: su: not found

Comment: @monok this implies super user privileges and it works for a rooted device. The emulator counts as one. Where from are you trying to run this command?

Comment: Meanwhile I found out that when I use a virtual device w/o Playstore I can run the command. Thanks.